# Python: Check for certain item names in body of text and compare with list of prices

Tags: python, search

I want to make a program that searches through a body of text (in this case a shopping list) for the name of certain items ('baked beans' etc). I then want it to check the price of those items from a list or some source of prices and create a total cost for the shopping list. How should I go about this?

Comment: Can you use a dictionary instead of a list? If so, I have a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = '''baked beans
spaghetti'''
prices = {'baked beans': 1.20, 'spaghetti': 1.30}
pricelist = [ ]

for line in iter(list.splitlines()):
    price = prices[line]
    pricelist.append(price)

total = sum(pricelist)
print total
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to assume anything about how you've formatted your shopping list.

```
list = "your formatting here"
prices = {
    "apple" : 0.99,
    "banana" : 0.29,
    "watermelon" : 4.99,
}
total = 0
for item in prices:
    if item in list:
        cost += prices[item]
```

`if item in list` searches for a substring in `list` equivalent to `item`, which isn't always fast. But I've assumed nothing about your formatting - if your items aren't multiple words (e.g. `toilet paper`) then you can split `list` and iterate over each element in the split list. @kirbyfan64sos suggested using [`string.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines), which is roughly equivalent to `string.split("\n")`.

*Edit*: just noticed that you said "check the price of those items from a list or some source of prices", so I assume you can use a `dict` as your source of prices. If not, maybe you can use a `list` of `tuples`...

```
prices = [("apple", 0.99), ("banana", 0.29), ("watermelon", 4.99)]
for item, price in prices:
    if item in list:
        cost += price
```